# What do "characteristics" and "properties" mean?

Tags: philosophy-of-science

I just want to know whether if the two terms "Characteristics" and "Properties" are same or different in science.

If these two terms are different in science then explain giving simple examples to differentiate these two terms
OR
Give examples by taking a person to explain the differences between two terms [For example - Take suppose a boy named Steve ,
who has a characteristic - ______
and properties - _______]

Answer (score 0):

Most people will be slipshod about word use and miss possible distinctions. The term characteristic suggests a quality that allows distinction from other things. Attribute suggests a quality we give to a thing. Property suggest an intrinsic or inherent quality which typically has explanatory or causal power.

A name, say, "Robert" or "Andrei", is typically an attribute.

Size is typically a characteristic, for all sorts of things of a very different nature, but you would expect fundamental things to have an inherent size.

Fundamental qualities such as quantum numbers may be typically thought of as inherent to things and therefore properties.

These distinctions may be seen as arbitrary but they resist erosion nonetheless.

Comment: Is it that both characteristics and properties measureable?

Comment: @user87284 Characteristics are typically empirical and so typically measurable. Actual properties may be measurable but we cannot tell! It may be that what we think are properties are in fact characteristics. Properties may not be necessarily measurable even if actual qualities. A particular case is qualia, if they are properties at all, since it doesn't seem that we can measure them. But it is also likely that we couldn't measure actual properties. We may have access only to characteristics that are consequences of properties. Bear in mind very many people are not aware of these distinctions.

Comment: Can you provide examples for better understanding of these two terms?

Comment: Examples must consist of both measurable and immeasurable part

Comment: Like Characteristics, measurable examples immeasurable examples and properties. measurable examples. Immeasurable examples

Comment: @user87284 I already did.

Comment: "Bear in mind very many people are not aware of these distinctions." Strange assertion, is this 'knowledge' special and private, if so how can it have any relevance or authority, or applicability?  Although Speakpigeon's definitions are acceptable, what is more important is that terminology changes over time and in respect to a given philosopher's usage. Properties are typically described as 'inhering' in a subject, like maleness or redness. Characteristics  are used to express qualities, like honesty, deceitfulness or integrity. But each word is formed in the 'imagination' and are elusive.

Comment: @CharlesMSaunders My opinion is that the definitions I give here all reflect the more intelligent and articulate use of these expressions. Many other people will have a different opinion. So what? The definitions I use are rooted in usage while most people are slipshod about their language.